# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(1-2c^2)^n \over n \ln{n} + \cos{n\pi}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(1-2c^2)^n \over n \ln{n} + \cos{n\pi}}$$
$c \in \mathbb{R}$. For what values of $c$ is this series:

1) convergent?

2) absolutely convergent?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: concentrate on the numerator. Do a case division $|c|>,=,<\sqrt{2}/2$. The denominator is pretty much irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Considering:
$$ n\log{n}+\cos{n\pi} = n\log{n}+(-1)^n \approx n\log{n} \quad\{\text{for}\,n\rightarrow\infty\} \quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad $$
Let:
$$\color{red}{A=1-2c^2} \quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad $$
Thus:
$$
\sum_{n=\color{red}{2}}^{\infty}\frac{A^n}{n\log{n}} = \begin{cases} 
-\infty\lt \,A\, \lt-1 &\Rightarrow \sum\frac{(-1)^n|A|^n}{n\log{n}} \space\space\space\quad\rightarrow\quad \text{Diverge by Limit test} \\[2mm] 
-1\,\,\lt \,A\, \lt0 &\Rightarrow \sum\frac{(-1)^n}{(1/|A|)^n n\log{n}} \space\rightarrow\quad \text{Converge by Ratio test} \\[2mm] 
\,\,\,0\,\,\,\lt \,A\, \lt+1 &\Rightarrow \sum\frac{1}{(1/|A|)^n n\log{n}} \space\rightarrow\quad \text{Converge by Ratio test} \\[2mm] 
+1\,\,\lt \,A\, \lt+\infty &\Rightarrow \sum\frac{|A|^n}{n\log{n}} \space\space\space\qquad\rightarrow\quad \text{Diverge by Limit test} \\[2mm] 
\end{cases}
$$
Also:
$$
\sum_{n=\color{red}{2}}^{\infty}\frac{A^n}{n\log{n}} = \begin{cases} 
A=-1 &\implies \sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n\log{n}} \quad\rightarrow\quad \text{Converge by Dirichlet test} \\[2mm] 
A=0 &\implies \sum\frac{(0)^n}{n\log{n}} = 0 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \\[2mm] 
A=+1 &\implies \sum\frac{1}{n\log{n}} \quad\rightarrow\quad \text{Diverge by Comparison test} \\[2mm] 
\end{cases}
$$
Hence:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-2c^2\right)^n}{n\log{n}+\cos{n\pi}} = \begin{cases} 
\text{Convergent for} &A\in\,\color{blue}{[}-1,\,+1\color{red}{[} \quad\rightarrow\quad c\in\,\color{blue}{[}-1,\,+1\color{blue}{]}-\color{red}{\{0\}} \\[2mm] 
\text{|Convergent| for} &A\in\,\color{blue}{]}-1,\,+1\color{red}{[} \quad\rightarrow\quad c\in\,\color{blue}{]}-1,\,+1\color{blue}{[}-\color{red}{\{0\}} \\[2mm] 
\end{cases}
$$
  
 
  
 
[image]